# Run microservices on Service Fabric in multiple Azure regions

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to use Service Fabric as a microservices orchestration for gaming backend. The game will be global, so what is the recommended solution for this architecture? Many clusters in separate regions for better performance? What about actor state in this solution? (I use cosmo db/SQL Server/ and actors in my microservices) I know that I can deploy Geo-HA Service Fabric Cluster on [this way](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/deploy-a-geo-ha-service-fabric-cluster-on-azure/) but is not officially supported and can be risky.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to deploy a multi region cluster, but it's hard to deal with latency issues properly.
I recommend taking a look at the [SF Mesh platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-overview#mission-critical-platform-capabilities) to run your services. It will support availability zones and multiple regions out of the box.

> Deploy applications across Availability Zones and multiple regions for
>   geo-reliability.

Note that at this time it's in public preview and it doesn't support the service & actor programming models.

[More info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU52ULgX7YU).

Comment: I can't use SF Mesh, it has some limitations and it is is not recommend to deploy app to production use.[info](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/azure-service-fabric-mesh-is-now-in-public-preview/). In addition, we have already implemented a lot of services on SF